# Migration to Angular 4 (Typescript) from Angular JS 1.x and compatible libraries

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an angular project and thinking to migrate all the way to angular 4 or 5 using typescript, almost convinced that we need to re-write most if not all the code we have, One issue is we do use some 3rd part directives/libraries from Angular Strap and Smart Table just to name the ones we use also a utility like lodash, I wonder if we can keep them in our markup or need to replace then with angular 4 compatible components